# Align text baseline to specific vertical ratio of image

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

Suppose I have the following <s>shitty</s> awesome logo with some artistic text in it that can not be rendered with a WebFont downloaded font

[image: A shitty logo with text]

Within the image the text baseline is 68% from the top / 32% from the bottom.

Now I'd like to align text of a HTML document, in which this image has been included into, with the baseline of the text in the image, which I know to be at a specific vertical ratio of the image height.

What CSS properties and which HTML `<div>` / `<span>` nesting structure do I need for this?

Comment: Are you working with dynamic font sizes? Does it have to be percentage?

Comment: @TanelEero: The image is a SVG and I'd prefer the font sizes not to be in absolute device units (pixels) but rather something relative (%, em) or in physical units (pt, mm). The website shall look good and consistent independent of the display device resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with is to use CSS3 transform with translateY. Something like this:

```
img {
    transfom:translateY(32%);
    -webkit-transfom:translateY(32%);
}
```

Working example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HhFLf/

Comment: Make sure to check out the browser support here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d